# TOpenPictureDialog and png_old extension

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

After adding a `TOpenPictureDialog` component, I noticed that, by default, the `Filter` property contains the "png_old" extension as its first element.

[image: Picture of the TOpenPictureDialog's Filter property editor in the IDE]

```
*.png_old;*.gif;*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp;*.tif;*.tiff;*.ico;*.emf;*.wmf
```

I've tried googling "png_old extension" but I didn't find anything (and some undesired websites appeared in the results).

Where does this extension come from? (Maybe something wrong on my system?)

Comment: Doesn't look like that on my 10.3.

Comment: Google strongly suggests this is a very uncommon thing to observe. I suspect it only happens on your system (or maybe, just maybe, only in XE7). Have you installed any graphics-related components in your IDE?

Comment: But it isn't unheard of. Here are two relevant matches: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=delphi+%22png_old%22 Are you using a localized version of RAD Studio?

Comment: And what's most strange is that at runtime, the property does not contains the "png_old" extension and the elements in the "All" item are in a different order: `ShowMessage(OpenPictureDialog1.Filter);` it produces: `All (*.bmp;*.tif;*.tiff;*.ico;*.emf;*.wmf)|*.bmp;*.tif;*.tiff;*.ico;*.emf;*.wmf|Bitmaps (*.bmp)|*.bmp|TIFF Images (*.tif)|*.tif|TIFF Images (*.tiff)|*.tiff|Icons (*.ico)|*.ico|Enhanced Metafiles (*.emf)|*.emf|Metafiles (*.wmf)|*.wmf`

Comment: I have got '*.png_old' my 10.3.3, but the order is different. Design time: *.gif;*.cur;*.pcx;*.ani;*.png_old;*.gif;*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.ico;*.emf;*.wmf;*.tif;*.tiff

Comment: The only "not standard" components that are installed on my IDE are: Korzh Localizer, FastReport, DevExpress, Woll2Woll, kbmMemTable and RX components. What do you mean with "localized version of RAD Studio"? How can I check for this?

Comment: I mean, is your RAD Studio in English or in Italian or some other language?

Comment: @TomBrunberg: I think the VCL's graphics system is internal to the VCL.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: It's in English

Comment: @Tamas: What IDE extensions/components have you installed? I suspect the culprit can be identified by taking the intersection of Fabrizio's and Tamas's IDE add-ons.

Comment: MMX, GExpert, JEDI, FastReport, DevExpress...

Comment: Google wasn't able to give me any hints. Perhaps you can search for `TPicture.RegisterFileFormat` or `png_old` on your disk(s) containing Delphi and third-party add-ons. `findstr /IS "TPicture.RegisterFileFormat" *.pas`

Comment: Yes, it is in the Fastreport, frxClass: ... LTPicture.RegisterFileFormat('PNG_OLD', 'Portable Network Graphics', TPNGObject);

Comment: Great, case closed! :)